# how to tweak the wind affecting the cloth simulation (flag)?

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

I have a wind blowing onto my flag, looks fine at the beginning but quickly becomes very static so the cloth barely moves. How can I tweak it? I`d like to apply file but cant find where to upload.

Edit

here`s file
[image]

Comment: Increase Random value or add keyframe to Strength value and in Graph editor assign Noise modifier to this curve. Tweak curvature for desire result.

Comment: To append file use  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and given code place into your original post via "edit".

Comment: thanks! Now I know!